# Wicket Problems about the textfield in the modal window

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket, wicket-6

First of all, thanks to all the people who would like to help me.
Sorry, my English is not so good, please use your imagination.

This problem is related to wicket.

More concretely,in the modal window,first typed in the textfield is no problem，but close the modal window,and open modal window again,textfield can't be typed.
In particular,this problem just appeared only in IE. But Chorme is no problem.

And this not my code is wrong,because example of the wicket official website is also have this problem(http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/ajax/modal-window)

1.Click "Show modal dialog with a page",in the pop-up windows,the textfield can be typed.

2.Then close the modal dialog,and click "Show modal dialog with a page" again.

3.In the pop-up windows,the textfield can not be typed.

Wicket version:7.2.0
IE version: 11

And my project must use IE.So,please help me,thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with IE11 and iframes:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-6082

I'd recommend using panel content for your modal windows instead.

Comment: Ok, I'll try.Thanks！